# How to push one xib file to another xib file in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iOS and I have created one tableList using `xib` file and when I click on tableList row, I want to push detail view controller but here `didSelectRow` is calling, but it's not pushing to details view controller. Please help me..

**my code:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Hello");

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 not required

Comment: Your hierarchy contains navigation controller??

Comment: yes i have navigation controller

Comment: try presenting your detail controller. if that works then you can narrow down the options.

Comment: if you dont mind please see my sample x code file  and please tell me what is mistack https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05NQoG9RAmwRmMxSGhKUE9tX1E/view?usp=sharing please help me

Comment: Try debugging it and see if detailVC is null or self.navigationController is null. Check if there is anything printed to the debug console, any error message or hint or so.

Comment: In your demo project code is a mess. There are two files DetailViewController (minimum, I did not check everything). No idea which of these is included in your bundle or if even boh are built into the bundle. You better tighten up your project structure or start with a new one from scratch. Thay may be easier and cleaner.

Comment: hi Hermann Klecker if i start with new project then fine everything? and i have already started with new project but no use i cant push another view controller